# Sum of consecutive salaries in the following output

Tags: oracle

I have a table of salaries I want to find sum of all the salaries consecutively in a different column based on the manager_id. Suppose I have a table like this

| Manager_id | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1200 |
| 100 | 1400 |
| 100 | 1600 |
| 103 | 1800 |
| 104 | 1900 |

And I want output like this

| Manager_id | Salary | Salary_Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1200 | 1200 |
| 100 | 1400 | 2600 |
| 100 | 1600 | 4200 |
| 103 | 1800 | 1800 |
| 104 | 1900 | 1900 |

Comment: [Edit] the question and post what you've tried yourself so far. Explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: You want this ordered by `manager_id, salary`? This looks like a salary history to me, but then you'd rather have a date column indicating when the new salary got effective, because salaries can get raised or lowered, so we cannot determine the order from the salaries alone.

Answer (score 1):

SUM analytical function can fulfil your requirement but there must some other column also to order your rows apart from Manager_id -

```
SELECT
  Manager_id,
  Salary,
  SUM(Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY Manager_id ORDER BY <other_column_for_ordering>) Salary_Sum
FROM salaries
ORDER BY Manager_id, <other_column_for_ordering>;
```

Comment: One must `partition by manager_id`, not `order by`. And I don't remember the defaults so woud always add `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`.

Comment: @Petr, Forgot to add Partition by in hurriedness. Added now. Also, there is no need to add rows between unbounded preceding and current row as it is by default.